# XPATH XML to Postgres SQL

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

This is my example of XML

```
<Data>
   <Month>11</Month>
   <Year>2021</Year>
   <Customer>
      <Name>ABC</Name>
   </Customer>
   <Contracts>
      <Contract Direction="OUT" count="60">
         <Partner>
            <Name>A</Name>
         </Partner>
         <Documents>
            <Document type="ORDER" count="10"/>
            <Document type="INVOICE" count="20"/>
            <Document type="OFFER" count="30"/>
         </Documents>
      </Contract>
      <Contract Direction="IN" count="47">
         <Partner>
            <Name>B</Name>
         </Partner>
         <Documents>
            <Document type="ORDER" count="47"/>
         </Documents>
      </Contract>
      <Contract Direction="OUT" count="37">
         <Partner>
            <Name>ABC</Name>
         </Partner>
         <Documents>
            <Document type="ORDER" count="37"/>
         </Documents>
      </Contract>
   </Contracts>
</Data>
```

and I'm using this SQL Syntax

```
SELECT 
    CAST(cast((xpath('//Year/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]as varchar) as integer) AS YearNo
    ,CAST(cast((xpath('//Month/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]as varchar) as integer) AS MonthNo
    ,(xpath('//Customer/Name/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))[1]::text AS CustomerName
    ,unnest(xpath('//Contracts/Contract/Partner/Name/text()', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))::text AS Partner
,unnest(xpath('//Contracts/Contract/@Direction', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))::text AS DocumentType
    ,unnest(xpath('//Contracts/Contract/Documents/Document/@type', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))::text AS DocumentType
    ,unnest(xpath('//Contracts/Contract/Documents/Document/@count', myTempTable.myXmlColumn))::text AS countDoc
FROM unnest(
    xpath
    (    '//Data'
        ,XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT convert_from(pg_read_binary_file('testXML.xml'), 'UTF8'))
    )
) AS myTempTable(myXmlColumn)
order by 5;
```

Issue is that results by partner and document type are wrong

[image]

Do you have any ideas ?

Additional do you have any ideas how to run this kind of script for more than 500 xml files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complex XML parsing is easier done using `xmltable()`. As far as I can tell, the following should return what you want:

```
select x.*
from the_table
  cross join xmltable('/Data/Contracts/Contract/Documents/Document'
            passing content
            columns
              year int path '//Year',
              month int path '//Month',
              customer_name text path '//Customer/Name',
              partner_name text path 'ancestor::Contract/Partner/Name',
              document_type text path 'ancestor::Contract/@Direction',
              type text path '@type',
              countdoc int path '@count'
            ) as x
```

Passing `'/Data/Contracts/Contract/Documents/Document'` as the initial XPath results in one row per `Document` in the result. The access to the attributes and elements "higher up", is then done using the `ancestor` selector for those that depend on the `Contract`.

The elements that are independent of the number of contracts are accessed through an absolute path starting at `//`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=de0be9e31a6fb0f426fb2c61655674be)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any ideas how to import multiple XML's from drive to table ?

Comment: @pt_zg each question here should be about one specific issue

Comment: Additional I found case where inside document array I have value something like this ```        <Documents>
            <Document type="ORDER" count="10">A</Document>
            <Document type="INVOICE" count="20">B</Document>
            <Document type="OFFER" count="30">C</Document>
         </Documents>``` How can I read this values (A, B, C) per each document ?